# How to get longest streak of consecutive days and current streak of consecutive days

Tags: node.js, postgresql, datetime

I'm making a habit builder app in which I want to keep track of a user's performance.

I want to get the longest streak of days a user performed a habit and the current streak of days a user performed a habit, don't mind the habit names it's just mock data for now.

Also weekDays in the habits table which represents the days in which a user wants to perform a habit is set to an array with Every day by default I'd appreciate advice on that decision since I'm not sure if that's the best way to store the week days in which a user wants to perform a habit.

users table:

```
id name email password role passwordResetToken passwordResetExpiresIn
```

habits table:

```
id   startDate      timer       userid  habitName       reminders        weekDays 
11  "2020-10-21"    "00:40:00"  32      "Data"          "{10:15:00}"    "{Everyday}"
12  "2020-10-21"    "00:10:00"  32      "Integration"   "{16:00:00}"    "{Everyday}"
13  "2020-10-21"    "00:10:00"  32      "Accountability""{13:40:00}"    "{Everyday}"
10  "2020-10-21"    "00:50:00"  32      "Mobility"      "{12:50:00}"    "{Everyday}"
9   "2020-10-21"    "00:15:00"  32      "Functionality" "{12:50:00}"    "{Everyday}"
```

history table:

```
id   cdate          checkIn    habitid  wasDone timeDone    weekDay userid

155 "2020-11-08"    "10:15:00"  9       true    "00:40:00"  "Sun"   32
157 "2020-11-17"    "23:00:00"  9       false   "00:40:00"  "Tue"   32
158 "2020-11-08"    "12:50:00"  9       true    "01:00:00"  "Sun"   32
159 "2020-11-07"    "10:15:00"  9       false   "00:50:00"  "Sat"   32
160 "2020-10-26"    "13:40:00"  9       true    "00:15:00"  "Mon"   32
```

Comment: I don't get the logic. Why is the `users` table empty? What is the relation between `habits` and `history`? And which result would you expect for this sample data?

Comment: The users table is not empty I just thought it wouldnt be necessasry to post part of its content, the relation between habits and history is that the history table stores whether a habit was done or not tracking the date in which it was one in "cdate" the time in which it was reported done in checkIn, the time spent doing the habit in timeDone and the weekDay in which it was done. The expected result is the longest streak of consecutive days performing a habit and the current streak of days performing the habit per user